# Authenticating the approved application ID/Key

Tags: desire2learn

I am trying to authenticate my application's `ID`/`Key` against one of our LMS environments. However, when I attempt to do so - I get the following error:

> "This application is not authorized on this LMS instance. Ask your administrator to authorize this application."

I can't figure out where the gap might be, because we have followed the same procedure to authenticate our previous app's `ID`/`Key` with their respective LMS environments. Additionally, if I use the same set of LMS credentials that I'm using in the App, but submit them to the LMS via a browser, it works fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If there is some relevant code that we could take a look at, it might help identify the problem. With only this much information, our ability to help you troubleshoot is very limited.

Comment: I just learnt that my application and the LMS is not in sync ,yet.Thats why the error.

Comment: Please post that as an answer to your own question - and then flag it as the correct one. :) This helps future users who might find this post with a similar concern understand what helped resolve it - and keeps our "Unanswered Questions" in the community from growing.

Answer (score 3):

I just learnt that my application and the LMS is not in sync ,yet.Thats why the error.

Comment: That is correct -- if you're getting that error back, the LMS' authentication process is telling you that your _application_ is not authorized to call its APIs. Once you have your App ID/Key pair granted, it can still take up to a full day for the LMS to receive the new App's information (and perhaps longer for their admins to enable your App for access to the APIs).